# How to test Azure Data factory linked service using API

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-management-api

I am trying to create and use Azure data factory by Rest API but while creation of linked service connection has created successfully but when I checked connection it got failed so is there anything to do test connection by API or PowerShell command.

Answer (score 1):

There is no this method in Microsoft documentation.You can track this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/38267635-test-connection-programmatically).

But there is a [blog](https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/9/23/adfv2-testing-linked-services) about testing link service by PowerShell.Here is the [script](https://gist.github.com/simondmorias/e4d9e7265a20af8d7d17b92d483e3889) on github.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can use one of cmdlet in `azure.datafactory.tools` PowerShell module:
[Test connection of Linked Service (preview)](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/azure.datafactory.tools#test-connection-of-linked-service-preview)

```
# Example 1
$LinkedServiceName = 'AzureSqlDatabase1'      
Test-AdfLinkedService @params -LinkedServiceName $LinkedServiceName
```

Alternatively, if you prefer, you can run such test as part of your CI/CD process in Azure DevOps installing #adftools extension, which uses the same PS module behind the scenes.
More: https://sqlplayer.net/adftools

*Disclaimer: I'm author of the tool.*